# Calling Go from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, go, cgo

I tried to run a simple in a go script from python and I got a segmentation fault. Here is my code:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    /*
typedef struct foo{
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int e;
int f;
} foo;
*/
    "C"
)

func main() {}

//export Foo
func Foo(t []int) C.foo {
    return C.foo{}
}
```

main.py

```
# loading shared object
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("main.so")

# go type
class GoSlice(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data", POINTER(c_void_p)), ("len", c_longlong), ("cap", c_longlong)]

lib.Foo.argtypes = [GoSlice]
lib.Foo.restype = c_void_p

t = GoSlice((c_void_p * 5)(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 5, 5)
f = lib.Foo(t)
print(f)
```

With that code, I got

```
140362617287784
[1]    23067 segmentation fault  python3 main.py
```

Now If I remove `e` and `f` from the `main.go` I got

```
None
```

and no more segmentation fault.

Why the number of members in the struct does matter here?

[EDIT] Both are running at the same place, I run one command `clear && go build -o main.so -buildmode=c-shared main.go && python3 main.py`

Comment: Are you sure your Python installation and Go generated library are both 32 or 64 bits?

Comment: @georgeok Hello, both are running on my computer at the same place with only one command `clear && go build -o main.so -buildmode=c-shared main.go && python3 main.py`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your GO/C code is correct. The problem is in the python script. The `lib.Foo.restype = c_void_p` call expects a void pointer but the library return a C struct. You need to define the return type a ctypes struct in python then it will work as you expect.

The **main.go**:

```
package main

import (
    /*
    typedef struct foo{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;
    int f;
    } foo;
    */
    "C"
)

func main() {
}

//export Foo
func Foo(t []int) C.foo {
    foo := C.foo{}
    foo.a = 1 // setting some values to avoid seeing zeros
    foo.b = 2
    return foo
}
```

The **main.py**:

```
from ctypes import *

# loading shared object
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("main.so")


# go type
class GoSlice(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("data", POINTER(c_void_p)), ("len", c_longlong), ("cap", c_longlong)]


class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a', c_int),
                ('b', c_int),
                ('c', c_int),
                ('d', c_int),
                ('e', c_int),
                ('f', c_int)]


lib.Foo.argtypes = [GoSlice]
lib.Foo.restype = Foo

t = GoSlice((c_void_p * 5)(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 5, 5)
f = lib.Foo(t)
print(f)
print(f.a)
print(f.b)
```

Then run `go build -o main.so -buildmode=c-shared main.go && python main.py` and it will print:

```
go build -o main.so -buildmode=c-shared main.go && python3 main.py 
<__main__.Foo object at 0x102608830>
1
2
```

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot. Actually, I read another topic on stackoverflow (I do not find it anymore) that explained (if I well understood) that c_void_p is enough as return type to handle struct. And since it was working for another struct of my program, I thought it was the correct way. Thank you for clarifying that.